# React Native extend NativeModules TypeScript types

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a native module and I would like to type it.

Here is an example of my module's interface

```
export interface BBAudioPlayer {
  playSound: (sound: 'click' | 'tada') => Promise<void>;
  pause: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

and that is how I use it:

```
NativeModules.BBAudioPlayer.playSound('tada');
```

How can extend `NativeModules` to add the types of my new module?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
// extendNativeModules.d.ts
// import original module declarations
import 'react-native';

export interface BBAudioPlayerInterface {
  playSound: (sound: 'click' | 'tada') => Promise<void>;
  pause: () => Promise<void>;
}

// and extend them!
declare module 'react-native' {

  interface NativeModulesStatic {
    BBAudioPlayer: BBAudioPlayerInterface;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ah awesome. thanks! One of the issues I had is, I had called the file index.d.ts inside my folder and it didn't get picked up. Renaming the file to something else worked.