# How to use an object with const assertion (as const) as an unique symbol for another type key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a list of routes :

```
const N: any = "N"; // get const from non typed lib for example or typed as "string"
const PREFIX = `Route_${N}` as const;
const Route = {
  Route1: `${PREFIX}_1`,
  Route2: `${PREFIX}_2`
} as const; // I use object litteral because enum doesn't allow computed value
```

I would like to type params for each route:

```
type ParamsList = {
  [Route.Route1]: undefined;
  [Route.Route2]: { value: string };
};
```

But it's not allowed with this TypeScript error:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

How can I use my route name as unique symbol key for my param list type ? const assertions (`as const`) should not make object keys unique ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce that error, everything looks fine in the TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLl0em).  Are you using an old version of TypeScript or something?  Without a [mre] it's hard to give any advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer**

Let's unpack the error message:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

"A computed property name" refers to the properties in your final `ParamsList` type - ( e.g. `Route.Route1` in `[Route.Route1]: undefined;`).

So typescript is saying `Route.Route1` must be an expression that ultimately evaluates to a "literal type" (e.g. a specific string like `"Route1_N_1"`, or a specific number like `42`), or a Symbol (not important here, but if you're curious, check [the Symbol docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html))

Here's what type `Route.Route1` currently evaluates to:

```
`Route_${any}_1`
```

This known as a "template literal type" (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)) - which is *not* the same thing as a literal string (e.g. `"Route_N_1"`). It sort of makes sense that TS would require this, too - it puts the compiler in a situation where it would be possible to have two (or more) different types defined for the same property on `ParamsList`, if there were multiple template literal types that could expand in overlapping ways.

So if you want to fix the problem, you need to somehow cause typescript to be able to evaluate `Route.Route1` to a specific string, not a generic one.

[The docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) that template literal types "have the ability to expand into many strings via unions," which is what you want. In order to trigger this, you must make sure that all the template positions (e.g. `${N}` in `Route_${N}` get fed specific literal string types (e.g. `"foo"` or `"bar"`, not things like `any` or `string`).

Here's one way to do this:

```
// const N: any = "N"; // original type "any" <--this won't work
const N = "N" as const; // new type "N" <-- this will

const PREFIX = `Route_${N}` as const; // new type: "Route_N"; original type: "Route_${any}"
const Route = {
  Route1: `${PREFIX}_1`, // new type: "Route_N_1"; original type: "Route_${any}_1"
  Route2: `${PREFIX}_2` // new type: "Route_N_2"; original type: "Route_${any}_2"
} as const;

type ParamsList = {
  [Route.Route1]: undefined;
  [Route.Route2]: { value: string };
};
```

See [this playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=6&jsx=3&pretty=true&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/PTAEGMHsDsGcBdQDkBcoCG0CeoC8oAiJAgblBFEgCcBLAcxunQBtR4sAHAU0MywNAAeALTD4ACxqxQAdxgByRHKoBrALAAoKHERI8hYhmnaEZCtC4y2nHkQEjhbSdJk1mzTZpOIACgCUAUQAxAEkADX0AAz9IAFd4LgB9ABIAbyQAX0ijCBhTcjALK3ZuNAIY+KTiMmp6RhZrUsIKhJTUvgyCLzzEFp58VM1QUD6ARjRItP9g8IzE0ciAGgLQIsauMr7EpHnSSloGJlYSjea41rSO3aGR864AJgmpwNCwufvs80t1zbvtxPue1qhwaJ1+lTaV0BmgyOW8JE8GhOoB86Co6AAtrAADJSRADG4AbT6ADoxgBdNCxaAAEy4ADNGFwaQiNMNiXcyXd7pTQKlQAA3FixU4IWjQOigDKs6VAA).

**Update: How to provide a string literal type to something if the library you're building with doesn't provide it**

In the above example, we're manually creating the `N` variable, so it's easy enough to provide a string literal type with `as const` assertion.

However, if `N` were actually something imported from another library, that had a type of `any`, we would need to somehow provide this type ourselves. As you pointed out in the comments, one way to do this would be to add an `as "MyString"` assertion to the end.

Another way would be to use [module augmentation combined with declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). In the specific example you provided in the comments, you were doing this:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, NativeModules } from "react-native";
const { NativeNaviagtion } = NativeModules;
// NativeNavigation.Page1 <-- this has type "any"
```

You can "augment" the NativeModules type provided by the `"react-native`" module so that `NativeModules.NativeNavigation.Page1` has a literal string type `"Page1"` by writing:

```
declare module "react-native" {
  interface NativeModulesStatic {
    NativeNaviagtion: { Page1: "Page1" };
  }
}
```

See [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-string-template-types-r9w47j?file=/src/App.tsx:626-739) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470191/4739687) for a similar problem in a different context.

**Old Answer**

Your original example (without the additional layer of indirection with `const N: any = "N"`) will work in TypeScript 4.1+, but not in TypeScript 4.0-. That's because TS added the [Template Literal Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) feature in 4.1.

Before 4.1, the `Route` const would have this type:

```
const Route: {
    readonly Route1: string;
    readonly Route2: string;
}
```

After 4.1, the `Route` const has this type:

```
const Route: {
    readonly Route1: "Route_1";
    readonly Route2: "Route_2";
}
```

So with 4.0- versions of typescript, this...

```
type ParamsList = {
  [Route.Route1]: undefined;
  [Route.Route2]: { value: string };
};
```

...would be interpreted as this...

```
type ParamsList = {
  [string]: undefined;
  [string]: { value: string };
};
```

...which is ambiguous, and throws that error. In 4.1+, that gets correctly interpreted as:

```
type ParamsList = {
    Route_1: undefined;
    Route_2: {
        value: string;
    };
}
```

Comment: I am using TS 4.6... but it's not working because of this:
`const PREFIX = "Route"; const Route = {Route1: \`${PREFIX}_1\`} as const;`
Using template string is considered as a "computed value" & it's not allowed in string enum. But In my case, I am sure that this value is constant at runtime. How to deal with it ?

Comment: Can you post a reproduction of the problem with TS 4.6? As jcalz pointed out [it appears to work fine without errors in the typescript playground in the latest versions](https://tsplay.dev/mLl0em). One random guess in the meantime - if you are using VSCode, sometimes it's possible that the version of typescript in your `package.json` doesn't match the version that VSCode is using (see [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions))

Comment: You right. I simplified to much my example. Consider this snippet: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=6&jsx=3&pretty=true&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAcgLhgQzATxgXhgIjjgbgFgAoUSWABQCUBRAMQEkANLGAA2pAFcoBTAPoASAN5wAvuxQQY5aMTLhoMLrz5sRpGCp78AjEnaiaDFuIF72AGi061AJkPG6TZufvtS46bKVQFpFBoAA7qlMgATsgAthAAMgCWytiaJNoA2qr8AHRZfHoAukjcYAAmfABmCWB8pQoZebm6fPZFMCIwAG7IADbcfEjQEdUA5jDiChNAA)

Comment: Thanks! I added a "new answer" section to my response above - does that help?

Comment: I have update my original example. As I mentioned in comment, I get a constant from a module/library that I don't have control on it and it's evaluated as `any`... 
`enum Page {
  GDB_PAGE = NativeNavigation.Page1, // NativeNavigation.Page1 is resolved as any, so typescript consider Pages as number enum...
}
const PREFIX = \`Route_${Pages.Page1}\` as const;`

Comment: Got it. So the nut of your problem is that somehow you'll need to get typescript to understand that the constant has a literal string type, not `any`. There are various ways of doing this - module augmentation, manual assertion, etc. I'm happy to take a look if you post a minimal reproducible example that includes how you're importing the constant and where its type definitions are coming from. Maybe on codesandbox or something similar?

Comment: npm install --save @types/react-native
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
const { NativeNavigation } = NativeModules; // typed as any here...
enum Page {   Page1 = NativeNavigation.Page1 }

The only workaround I found, it's to cast every constant with string literal...:
`enum Page {   Page1 = NativeNavigation.Page1 as "Page1" }`

Comment: I updated the answer with a section on "How to provide a string literal type to something if the library you're building with doesn't provide it".